# Lerna w/ Nx Is there a way to get console output "simpler"?

Tags: nrwl-nx, lerna

The nice graphical flourishes that come with enabling Nx in Lerna does not play nicely when piped to text editors or in Webstorm terminal. Is there a setting similar to `--progress=plain` in docker that will not use TUI elements?

Example junk found after piping to vim:
(That ^[ is a `` character)

[image]